Mule 4 Database Connector Execute Script
I am using the execute script function in the database connector of Mule 4. How do I capture the success or failure of the script? The response payload always has a -2, but I was under the impression that I should get a 0 or 1 result depending on success or failure of the script.
Any advice would be appreciated!
Ran executre script, expected a 0 or 1 result but got -2. Always get -2.

Please read How to Ask. Your question should include details like code, configurations, etc, In this case you should add the XML text of the execute operation, what is the database and version, JDBC driver used including version, and any other details that help to understand and reproduce the issue. See also How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

There is nothing called "MuleSoft 4". The product is "Mule 4". The company is called "MuleSoft".

From the documentation the execute script operation of the Database Connector returns an array of numbers. The size of the array is the number of statements in the the script. Each number is the number of records affected by that statement:

Executing a script returns an array of integers, one element per executed statement. Each integer represents the number of objects affected by the statement.

For it to return a negative number something must have failed in the execution. It is impossible to say what is the cause since you haven't shared any details.

that's because the exact script that's being run I can't post. But something you said exactly illustrates the problem. You said something must have failed in the execution. Except when the script is run manually it works, so nothing fails.

You should provide more reproduction/debugging details. We will not be able to help. Try creating a reduced script that you can share. That's what a minimal reproducible example is about.
